# lint error "Call requires API level 24" whereas desugaring is correctly configured to use Java 8 features

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint

My app has `minSDKVersion 16`.

I have followed the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) and added the following lines to my build.gradle in order to use some "Java 8 language APIs without requiring a minimum API level":

```
android {
    compileOptions {
            coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

This works as expected, and the following code does not crash at runtime on an API 16 emulator:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add("hello");
// ↓ this is a Java 8 API and crashes on API 16 if coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled=false
arr.removeIf(s -> true);
```

Now, the issue is that lint shows an error on this line:
`Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.ArrayList#removeIf`

[image: lint error]

**How can I fix this incorrect behavior of Android Studio/lint?**

I don't want to suppress the error because it could be useful, when actually legitimate.

Comment: Have you set the source and target compatility to Java 8? Like in instructions here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Comment: @Jakoss yes, source and target compatility are set to Java 1.8.

Comment: @Sébastien Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Prudhvi Nope..

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too. Trying to figure out how to turn off the lint errors.